# What is the term of a component drawn surrounded by another component?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Having a drawing (see image) of an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ where

- $V = \{A,B,C,D,E,F,G\}$ and $v \in V$
- $E = \{\{A,B\},\{B,C\},\{C,D\},\{D,A\},\{D,E\},\{E,F\},\{F,G\},\{G,E\}\}$
- each vertex $v$ has a position $\lambda$

  - $\lambda_v = \{x, y\}$

**After removing edge $\{D,E\}$, two components $c_1$ and $c_2$ exists. Is there a term for the component $c_2 = \{\{E,F\},\{F,G\},\{G,E\}\}$ surrounded by $c_1$?**

[image: Drawing of Graph $G$]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way to express this is that component $c_1$ is not simply connected (it has a hole). Of course, this doesn't help to give a term for $c_2$, but in analogy with political maps, we might call it an **[enclave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclave_and_exclave)**.